# SpriteKit Objective-C calling a code block which takes one parameter

Tags: objective-c, parameters, objective-c-blocks

I first define:

```
 void (^cb)(NSUInteger) = ^void(NSUInteger number) {
        //SOME OTHER CODE ....

        [self.gamePlayLogic removeHeroMovementSegmentLine:number];
 };
```

and then I am making an SKAction (of type `runBlock`) from it, passing it one parameter, like this:

```
    NSUInteger movementActionsSoFar = [self.movementActions count];
    SKAction * codeCompletionAction = [SKAction runBlock:cb(movementActionsSoFar)];
```

Still, this doesn't work and I am getting error message:

```
Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'dispatch_block_t _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^)(void)')
```

What am I doing wrong here, guys? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `cb(movementActionsSoFar)`, you're actually telling the compiler to *execute* the `cb` block with `movementActionsSoFar` as a parameter, and then pass the result of that to `-[SKAction runBlock:]`. The result of the `cb` block is `void`, which is not what `-[SKAction runBlock:]` expects—it wants a block.

Instead of this, you can encase the `cb` block inside another block, like so:

```
[SKAction runBlock:^{ cb(movementActionsSoFar); }];
```